# Realm Generate Model

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I have been following [this](http://www.appcoda.com/realm-database-swift/) tutorial on Realm, and I have hit a block.
So it says to generate a Realm model, for which we have to install a plugin in Xcode, through Alcaraz. Shinny.

Now the problem which I am facing is that in Xcode 8+ is that it does NOT allow to install any external plugin( Only those which can edit text as far as I could understand).

My question is that how do I generate Realm Model like this tutorial says so, now that Xcode 8+ does not support external plugins. Also if its not possible now, then how should I approach/solve this mapping of data model.

I have found nothing or NO solution in Realms git page or their website.
Any help is appreciated.

I am using Xcode 8.3.2, and I am working on Swift 3.1

## EDIT

I have installed Realm, via cocoapods already. I am asking that if there is any visual generator like Core Data xcdatamodel, for Realm Data model, as it was before in the Xcode plugin.

Comment: no need for pluging just use   "pod 'Realm'"import realm and create a class and sbclass with RLMObject.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use CocoaPods

add following to pods file and install -pod install

 pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
  pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true

  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
          end
      end
  end

then , Create model class as following

import Foundation
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class ClassName: Object{

required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value : value,schema:schema)
        //fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
        //fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm:realm , schema:schema)
        //fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no visual model generator for Realm. Even in the tutorial you linked, there is no mention of such thing. The XCode plugin just generates a skeleton Swift file that can be used as your Realm model, there is no visual generator.

The visual tool you see in the link is [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12), but it's main purpose is to check your database entries, you can't create models with it.

Comment: Visual browser part I get it, 
So I just create a swift file, edit it by subclassing it to an arbitary `Object` class which doesnt exists at all, and then import `RealmSwift` to take away the compile error? 
This i have to apply everytime?

Comment: You can create your Realm models in any Swift file, you don't necessarily need to create them in a separate file. However, I think it is better practice to have all your Realm model definitions in the same file, at least for me it makes things more clear.
[Object](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html) is not an "arbitrary" class, it is the base class Realm uses, so yes, you have to subclass Object if you want to create a Realm model class. See [Realm models documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Visual Realm Editors now:

1. **RealmObjectEditor** [by Ahmed-Ali](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/RealmObjectEditor) (Description below is from github: )

> - Using **Realm Object Editor** you will be able to:
>
>   - Create Realm Entities.
>   - Create the entities attributes and define the properties for each attribute (primary key, index, ignored, default value, etc...)
>   - Create one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.
>   - Set a perant class for each entity (the default is RLMObject for cocoa-based entities and RealmObject for Java entities)
>   - Export the designed schema into Swift, Objective-C or Java for Android.

2. **GYRO** [by NijiDigital](https://github.com/NijiDigital/gyro)  (Description below also from github)

> - Gyro is a tool to generate Realm model classes, for both Android (Java & Kotlin) and iOS/macOS (Swift), from an .xcdatamodel file.
> - The .xcdatamodel file is usually used to represent Core Data entities in Xcode in a graphical way. It can be created or edited with
>     a graphical user interface in Xcode.
> - But with Gyro, you will now be able to use an xcdatamodel to create a Realm model files as well!
> - This will allow you to design your model in a visual way (rather than by code), only once (rather than once for Android and once for
>     iOS), and have the code generated for you.

RealmObjectEditor looks quite promising. GYRO needs a model file...
Try it out and let me know if it helps...

**Edit:** Seems RealmObjectEditor is programmed in swift 2. Needs to be updated to at least swift 3 to be able to use it... Too bad...Anybody with XCode 8? (Error Message: The target “Realm Object Editor” contains source code developed with Swift 2.x. This version of Xcode does not support building or migrating Swift 2.x targets. **Use Xcode 8.x to migrate the code to Swift 3.**)